# Azure monitor metric alerts- what happens if i leave out dimensions?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-monitoring

I have this metric alert

```
{
      "type": "microsoft.insights/metricAlerts",
      "apiVersion": "2018-03-01",
      "name": "RequestsForWebsite",
      "location": "global",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites',variables('webSiteName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/actionGroups', 'defaultactionname')]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "description": "Website requests",
        "severity": 2,
        "enabled": true,
        "scopes": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('webSiteName'))]"
        ],
        "evaluationFrequency": "PT5M",
        "windowSize": "PT5M",
        "criteria": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "criterionType": "DynamicThresholdCriterion",
              "name": "Requests",
              "metricName": "Requests",
              "metricNamespace": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
              "operator": "GreaterOrLessThan",
              "timeAggregation": "Average",
              "dimensions": [
                {
                  "name": "Instance",
                  "operator": "Include",
                  "values": ["*"]
                }
              ],
              "alertSensitivity": "High",
              "failingPeriods": {
                "numberOfEvaluationPeriods": 1,
                "minFailingPeriodsToAlert": 1
              }
            }
          ],
          "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor.MultipleResourceMultipleMetricCriteria"
        },
        "actions": [
          {
            "actionGroupId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/actionGroups', 'defaultactionname')]"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

I have set the dimension to *, here for Instance. Does this mean that i my webapp run with one instance at the alert creation, but scale up to two (with autoscaling), it is monitoring those two? What if the opposite is going to happen: what if i leave the dimension array empty, will it then only monitor the one instance that was at the creation of the alert, and it will not monitor instance number two, if autoscale is activated.

I can't find anything in the documentation that describe this.

**UPDATE**

I have just read this

> You can also Select * for any of the dimensions. Select * will
>   dynamically scale the selection to all current and future values for a
>   dimension.

here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-metric#create-with-azure-portal. It still doesn't tell me what happens when not selecting "select *".